# Tesseract.js doesn't recognize Arabic language

Tags: javascript, tesseract.js

I'm using tesseract.js ORC library to read what is written on an image and write it in console or on a text file so I found this library and it's working find with English word or characters but when I tried to read what is written on the image in Arabic language it doesn't work so this is the image that I'm trying to read

[image]

and this is my code :-

Head Tag:-

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.1.0/dist/tesseract.min.js'</script>
```

Body Tag:-

```
    <script>
        Tesseract.recognize(
        'image.png',
        'ara',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the result inside the `.then()` block.

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/xa7c5ofz/) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> OCR TEST </title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.1.0/dist/tesseract.min.js"></script>
<output id="result">Processing...</output>
<script>
  const output = document.querySelector('output#result');
  Tesseract.recognize(
    'https://i.imgur.com/mdzmK4w.png', 'ara'
  ).then(result => {
    output.value = result.data.text;
  }).catch(err => {
    output.value = 'Processing Failed';
    console.log(err);
  });
</script>
```

It can take some time to process, especially on the first load because the WASM module and OCR training data will be fetched in the background first. You can see this happening in the Network tab of your Dev Tools.